# Testing a Rails gem with test/dummy app, /tmp folder gets clobbered...somehow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems

I'm writing a gem that has to select which version of a XYZ.js file to make available to sprockets `//= require "XYZ"` statements based on configuration at app startup. My solution is to copy the `XYZ.variant.js` or `XYZ.variant2.js` to `/tmp/cache/<gemname>/XYZ.js` in the Rails app. This seems to work if I manually test; if I go to the `test/dummy` folder and test the functionality via `rackup` the `XYZ.js` is properly found. If I test the gem via another rails app, it works (via `path:` in Gemfile).

But, when I run the test suite for this gem, it fails, because at some point after the initial copy to `/tmp/cache/<gemname>/XYZ.js`, the whole tmp folder gets cleared, and the only thing in it by the time the test actually gets run is `/tmp/cache/assets`. I don't understand how this could be behaving different b/w the test suite and the other 2 working methods. It's as if the initialization order is different or something. Is there something special that running via `rackup` would do that would change the initialization order?

Note that the test suite worked fine before this particularly addition to the code that did the tmp copying. It's just the normal `enginex` code that would have been generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with initializers, but rather another test case (for generators) that was clobbering the tmp folder.